# Elevation of An TouchableOpacity Not Working on Carousel Image, React Native

Tags: react-redux, react-native

```
<View style={{alignItems:'center',marginTop: 15, height:320,backgroundColor:'#fff',paddingTop:10}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{position:'absolute',right:15,top:25,elevation:2}}>
         <Icon  name="share-social-outline" size={30} color="#0057ff"/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
         
        <Carousel
                autoplay
                autoplayTimeout={5000}
                loop
                index={0}
                pageSize={BannerWidth}

            >
                {images.map((image, index) => renderPage(image, index, navigation))}
            </Carousel>
        
        </View>
    </View>
```

I used TouchableOpacity on icon and Gave Elevation to Touchable Opacity which is on image carousel, Its Not working. Please Help

Comment: Wrap the touchable opacity to a view.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by experimenting myself; In Order To get Touchableopacity on icon over Image Carousel, we just need to use 'zIndex=3' Not 'elevation'.